# CustomAdapter does not show any items in Listview

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I want to display user chats from a Firebase List in a ListView with a custom Adapter. But somehow it does not work. I get a response when I try to look at the data in the logcat but when I pass the list to the CustomAdapter it does not display anything in my ListView. What is the issue?

My Adapter:

```
public class ChatAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private Activity context;
    private List<Chats> chatsList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ChatAdapter(Activity Context, List<Chats> chatsList) {
        super(Context, R.layout.abc_main_chat_item);
        this.context = Context;
        this.chatsList = chatsList;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View listViewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.abc_main_chat_item, null, true);

        TextView tvusername = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.group_name);
        TextView tvuid = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.useruid);
        TextView tvlastmessage = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.latestMessage);
        TextView tvlastmessagetime = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.latestMessageTime);
        ImageView ivphoto = (ImageView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.profileImg);

        tvusername.setText(chatsList.get(position).getUsername());
        tvlastmessage.setText(chatsList.get(position).getLastMessage());
        tvlastmessagetime.setText(chatsList.get(position).getLastMessageTime());
        tvuid.setText(chatsList.get(position).getUseruid());
        Picasso.with(getContext()).load(chatsList.get(position).getPhotoURL()).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_person_grey_round).into(ivphoto);

        listViewItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(context, Chat_Room.class);
                i.putExtra("room_name", chatsList.get(position).getUsername());
                i.putExtra("room_uid", chatsList.get(position).getUseruid());
                context.startActivity(i);

            }
        });

        listViewItem.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.abcd_listview_alertdia_layout);
                ArrayList<String> list_of_chats = new ArrayList<>();
                final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
                arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list_of_chats);

                list_of_chats.add(0, "Chatverlauf mit "+ chatsList.get(position).getUsername()+" löschen?");
                list_of_chats.add(1, "Profil von "+chatsList.get(position).getUsername()+" anschauen");
                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                final ListView lv = (ListView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.lv);
                lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
                lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position2, long id) {
                        if (position2 == 0) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                            alert.setTitle("Chatverlauf mit "+chatsList.get(position).getUsername()+" löschen?")
                                    .setMessage("Du kannst das Löschen nicht rückgängig machen. Bist du dir sicher?")
                                    .setNegativeButton("Abbrechen", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                            dialog.cancel();
                                        }
                                    })
                                    .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("chats").child("userchats").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).child(chatsList.get(position).getUseruid()).setValue(null);
                                            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("chats").child("users").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("messages").child(chatsList.get(position).getUseruid()).setValue(null);
                                        }
                                    }).setCancelable(true)
                                    .show();
                            lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
                            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                        if (position2 == 1) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(context, ViewContact.class);
                            intent.putExtra("useruid", chatsList.get(position).getUseruid());
                            context.startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    }
                });
                dialog.show();
                return true;
            }
        });

        ivphoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.abcd_profile_pic_dialog_layout);
                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.alertImage);
                TextView textView = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.alertdialogtv);
                ImageView message = (ImageView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.alertMessage);
                ImageView profile = (ImageView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.alertProfile);
                profile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(context, ViewContact.class);
                        intent.putExtra("useruid", chatsList.get(position).getUseruid());
                        context.startActivity(intent);
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                message.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), Chat_Room.class);
                        intent.putExtra("room_name", chatsList.get(position).getUsername());
                        intent.putExtra("room_uid", chatsList.get(position).getUseruid());
                        context.startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
                Picasso.with(getContext()).load(chatsList.get(position).getPhotoURL()).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_person_grey_round).into(imageView);
                textView.setText(chatsList.get(position).getUsername());
                dialog.setCancelable(true);
                dialog.show();
            }
        });

        return listViewItem;
    }
    ...
}
```

And this is how I get the data for the List:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("chats").child("userchats").child(myUiD).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        List<chatapp.chatapp2.Chats.Chats> chatsList = new ArrayList<chatapp.chatapp2.Chats.Chats>();

        for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

            chatapp.chatapp2.Chats.Chats chats = new chatapp.chatapp2.Chats.Chats();

            chats.setUsername(snapshot.child("roomname").getValue().toString());
            chats.setPhotoURL(snapshot.child("photoURL").getValue().toString());
            chats.setLastMessage(snapshot.child("lastMessage").getValue().toString());
            chats.setLastMessageTime(snapshot.child("lastMessageTime").getValue().toString());
            chats.setUseruid(snapshot.child("userUiD").getValue().toString());
            chatsList.add(chats);
            Log.d("CHATS", chats.getUsername());
            Log.d("CHATS", chats.getUseruid());
        }
        ChatAdapter chatAdapter = new ChatAdapter(getActivity(), chatsList);
        chatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        listView.setAdapter(chatAdapter);
        listView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    ...
});
```

Comment: Why you create `listview` inside `ArrayAdapter`?

Comment: Obviously because you didn't pass list to ask class... Do not use ArrayAdapter(as you as many others using it wrong) but use BaseAdapter.. Also calling notifyDataSetChanged before adapter is used doesn't make sense.

Comment: I create a View not a ListView in my ArrayAdapter

Answer (score 0):

I dont really know why it does not worked, but I found the Solution:

You have to override the getCount method like this:

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return chatsList == null ? 0 : chatsList.size();
}
```

I do not know what it does but it works :) :)